# bsd (osx) pf nat - change source port on outgoing UDP packets

Tags: macos, port, nat, bsd, pf

I am running docker-machine on osx. docker-machine is running NAT so when my container send out a UDP packet on port 1812, NAT is translating it to some random port.
I am playing around with pf nat (on the host) so I can get osx to just change the source port on these outgoing packets back to 1812.

I imagine this would work - but it doesnt

```
nat on en0 proto udp from any to any -> (en0) port 1812
```

I`m hoping some pf/bsd experts can help me with this.
I have no concern for security or anything at this point - just trying to test a theory on how a particular device responds to source port.